# login using passport always get error 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

hi i'm using express to implements passport, but i don't knows when i'm hit login url i always get error 400 bad request. This is my code :

main.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

require('./config/passport');
require('./config/static')(app, express);
require('./config/routes')(app);
require('./config/seed')();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

passport.js :

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../api/model/user.model');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

routes.js :

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/api/sign_in', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
    res.json(res.body);
    });

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'));
    });
};
```

and when i'm hit url "/api/sign_in" with 'POST' method with parameter '{email: "john@local.com", password: "12345"}', i'm get error bad request 400

Comment: don't see any `body-parser` for json

Comment: oh god, you right i'm forgotten it :)
thanks @hassansin

Comment: You are using res.body in the callback. it must be req.body

Comment: thanks @Koder, i already fix it :)